# Textarea overflows div even with box-sizing:border-box

Tags: css, html, textarea

I'm trying to have a textarea expand to fit 100% of its parent div, but I'm having issues in IE9. The following is the entirety of the page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #wrap {
        width: 50%;
        height: 100px;
        background:#fee; border:3px double #f99;
    }

    textarea {
        background:#efe;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        border:0; margin:0;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        overflow: auto;
        display: block;    
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap"><textarea>hello world</textarea></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this image shows the result.
[result http://polybemani.net/uploader/files/1/cssboxsizing.png](http://polybemani.net/uploader/files/1/cssboxsizing.png)

It shows up fine in Chrome, but no go in IE9 and IE10. What I don't understand is that with the exact same code, it works fine in jsfiddle. What gives?

Comment: set `border:0; padding:0` for textarea

Comment: I created this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/W9dGE/1/ and it works totally fine in IE9 for me. Can you confirm whether it's working for you in the fiddle?

Comment: It works in the fiddle, but not on my actual page.

Answer (score 0):

The answer:

Adding

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

to the head tag fixed the issue. Apparently IE was in quirks mode. The more you learn!

Hopefully this helps the next person running into this issue!

Full source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #wrap {
            width: 50%;
            height: 100px;
            background:#fee;
            border: 3px solid red;
        }

        textarea {
            background:#efe;
            padding: 10px;
            border:0; 
            margin:0;
            box-sizing:border-box;
            overflow: auto;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap"><textarea>hello world</textarea></div>
</body>
</html>
```